# Is it possible to overload an operator taking references/pointers to an abstract class as input?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, operator-overloading

I am working on a c++ programme that has to carry out differentiation *by symbol* of a given expression. For example, the derivative of `(5x)` will be `((0*x) + (5*1))` . Note that the integer coefficient is also treated as a variable or function hence, the product rule is used. Another example: `(5 + (8 * x))` will evaluate to `(0 + ((0*x) + (8*1)))` . No further simplication is required.

The task requires that there be an abstract base class "Expression" with pure virtual methods and from it must stem derived classes such as Number, Variable etc. The goal is to read expressions of the form given above and print out their respective symbol-derivatives.

I have had some success in tackling this task without overloading any operators. Here is what I mean:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class Expression
{
public:
    virtual Expression* diff() = 0; //Derivative Calculator
    virtual void print() = 0;
    virtual std::string stringget() = 0; //Prints current expression
};


//--------------------Number Class--------------------//
class Number : public Expression
{
private:
    int num;
    std::string snum;

public:

    //Constuctors
    Number(int n) : num(n), snum(std::to_string(num)) { }
    Number() : num(0), snum("0") { }

    // Rule of three does not apply as class does not contain pointer variables

    //Differentiation function
    Expression* diff()
    {
        num = 0;
        snum = std::to_string(0);
        return this;
    }

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << num << std::endl;
    }

    std::string stringget()
    {
        return snum;
    }

};


//--------------------Variable Class--------------------//
class Variable : public Expression
{
private:
    std::string var;

public:

    //Constructors
    Variable(std::string v) : var(v) { }
    Variable() : var("x") { }

    //Functions
    Expression* diff() override
    {
        var = "1";
        return this;
    }

    void print() override
    {
        std::cout << var << std::endl;
    }

    std::string stringget() override
    {
        return var;
    }

};



//--------------------Addition/Sum Class--------------------//
class Add : public Expression
{
private:
    std::string sum;
    std::string plus = "+";
    std::string leftpar = "(";
    std::string rightpar = ")";
    Expression* laddend; //left addend storage
    Expression* raddend; //right addend storage


public:
    //Constructors
    Add(Expression* a, Expression* b)
    {
        sum = leftpar + (*a).stringget() + plus + (*b).stringget() + rightpar;
        laddend = a;
        raddend = b;
    }
    Add(Expression& a, Expression& b)
    {
        sum = leftpar + (a).stringget() + plus + (b).stringget() + rightpar;
        laddend = &a;
        raddend = &b;
    }

    //Copy Constructor
    Add(const Add& src) : sum(src.sum), plus(src.plus), leftpar(src.leftpar), rightpar(src.rightpar), laddend(src.laddend), raddend(src.raddend) { }

    //Assignment operator
    Add& operator =( Add& src ) { sum = src.sum; return *this; }

    //Destructor
    ~Add() { delete laddend; delete raddend; laddend = NULL; raddend = NULL;}

    //
    void print() override
    {
        std::cout << sum << std::endl;
    }

    //derivative calculator
    Expression* diff() override
    {
        laddend = (*laddend).diff();
        raddend = (*raddend).diff();
        sum = leftpar + (*laddend).stringget() + plus + (*raddend).stringget() + rightpar;
        return this;
    }

    //Expression getter
    std::string stringget() override
    {
        return sum;
    }

    //Overload
    Expression& operator +( Expression* rhs)
    {
        Add* res = new Add(this, rhs);
        return *res;                        
    }
};


//--------------------Product/Multiplication Class--------------------//
class Mul : public Expression
{
private:
    std::string product = "(";
    std::string ast = "*";
    std::string plus = "+";
    std::string leftpar = "(";
    std::string rightpar = ")";
    Expression* multiplicand; //left argument storage
    Expression* multiplier; //right argument storage

public:
    //Constructors
    Mul(Expression* a, Expression* b)
    {
        product = product + (*a).stringget() + ast + (*b).stringget() + rightpar;
        multiplicand = a;
        multiplier = b;
    }

    void print() override
    {
        std::cout << product << std::endl;
    }

    Expression* diff() override
    {
        std::string lvar = (*multiplicand).stringget(); //before differentiation
        std::string rvar = (*multiplier).stringget();   //before differentiation

        multiplicand = (*multiplicand).diff();
        multiplier = (*multiplier).diff();
        product = leftpar + leftpar + (*multiplicand).stringget() + ast + rvar + rightpar + plus + leftpar + lvar + ast + (*multiplier).stringget() + rightpar + rightpar;
        return this;
    }

    std::string stringget() override
    {
        return product;
    }


    //Overload
    Expression& operator *( Expression* rhs)
    {
        Mul* res = new Mul(this, rhs);
        return *res;                        
    }
};



int main()
{
    Expression* test = new Mul(new Number(6), new Variable("x"));

    std::cout << "Current Expression: " << test->stringget() << std::endl;

    Expression* test2 = test->diff();

    std::cout << "Differentiated Expression: " << test2->stringget() << std::endl;
    Add x(test, test2);
    //  x = test + test2 * test;
delete test;



    return 0;
}
```

Which successfully compiles with the following output:

```
Current Expression: (6*x)
Differentiated Expression: ((0*x)+(6*1))
```

Now, the expression `(6*x)` was created by means of the line
 `Expression* test = new Mul(new Number(6), new Variable("x"));` 
But since my goal is to read expressions of the form `(6*x)` and even more complex expressions e.g `(((4*x)+(x*x))-x)` and then interpret them and finally differentiate, the only way is to overload the operators. This is where I'm getting problems.

**The Problems**

As you have might have noticed in the code, I have overloaded the addition and multiplication operators. However, when I try to run code such as

`x = test + test2 * test1;`

(This line is commented out in the provided code above) I get an error. Moreover, even with just one operator, for instance,

`test = test + test2;`

I get the error

`error: invalid operands of types 'Expression*' and 'Expression*' to binary 'operator+'|`

or

`error: invalid operands of types 'Expression*' and 'Expression*' to binary 'operator+'|`

This doesn't make sense to me since the parameter types coincide.

**What Else Have I tried?**

I've tried to pass the parameters by reference, as well as by const reference but still the same result. I also tried to write the operator overload description as a non-member function but that gives the error

```
must have an argument of class or enumerated type
```

I have also tried changing the return types from `Expression&` to `Expression*` and making the necessary subsequent edits but the errors are the same. I've even tried to implement the rule of threes for all the classes - even though it is not necessary - but the result is the same.

I'd appreciate any help on where I am missing it.

Comment: You have too much code. You should cut it down until you get an [mcve] that still reproduce the error

Comment: I did follow the guide and reduced it to the main part. The thing is, much of it is interdependent.

Comment: @E.Nole: We don’t need to see the differentiation part, just a class with an operator that doesn’t work.

Comment: (1)  Yes, it is possible to overload some (not all) operators to accept a reference to an abstract type.   Your code is not in good shape to do that though.   (2)  You say it is unnecessary to follow the rule of three - and you are deeply incorrect.  Your code, as shown, has numerous memory leaks, and would benefit from proactive resource management and cleanup - which the rules of 3, 5, and/or zero support.

Comment: @DavisHerring the functions `Expression* diff()` implemented in the inherited classes are ones that handle differentiation. The program isn't supposed to handle expressions such as elementary functions (trigonometric, exponential etc). Only expressions involving constants and variables of degree 1 as well as their sum, product, difference and quotient. I have removed the functions that implement the quotient rule to cut down the code.

Comment: @Peter Are the `+` and `*` among the operators that can't be overloaded in this way? Kindly explain what you mean. What is the requirement that I have to work on to be able to overload the operators? Regarding memory leaks, I've edited the one in the main function (which is the only instance of heap memory allocation). Regarding (2), I meant that the rule of three implementation is not necessary in the classes above because none of them so far use heap-allocated memory. Also, a shallow copy is sufficient for the member variables thus, the default copy constructor will suffice.

Comment: Pointers are not references. You cannot overload operators for pointers. Pointers are spelled with a `*` in the type. References are spelled with a `&` in the type.

Comment: @n.m. As I mentioned in the post, I already tried both approaches and got the same error. To be sure, I've tried it again; I replaced the current snippet with this `Expression& operator +( Expression& rhs) { Add* res = new Add(this, &rhs);  return *res; }`  And I get the same error as described in the question.

Comment: `test` is a pointer. An operator overloaded for references won't work with pointers. You need `*test + *test2` or something.

Comment: Binary operators (like `operator+()`) can be overloaded.   Assuming you're overloading the non-member form, at least one of the arguments needs to be of a class type, or a reference to a class type.   As n.m said, an operator overloaded for references won;t work with pointers.

Comment: @n.m. I did indeed edit the subsequent changes to the expression in the main function. With `x = *test + *test2;` the error is `error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'Expression' and 'Expression') `

Comment: @Peter I get the same error when I try to overload the operator+ with references (See the code sample in the comments above). I have also tried to overload by `const reference` - also to no avail.

Comment: A pointer and a reference are not interchangeable. If a function accepts an argument by reference don't pass a pointer (and vice versa). Your recurring problem is that you are mixing usage of pointers and references as if they are interchangeable.  You've be better off redesigning your classes from scratch, and using references correctly.   Your usage of `new` to create values is all wrong in C++   (in fact, it appears you are using techniques from Java, but they work differently in C++, hence your problems).

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not a series of confusing and incomplete comments.

Comment: By the way "the only way is to overload the operators" is absolutely not true. The form of your input has nothing to do with the syntax you use to write your program. `*` in the imput doesn't have to correspond to `*` in the program text. You can write this program in any programming language, regardless of its ability to overload anything.